# Can we use mayonnaise as a fermentation agent for liquid fertilizer?

Tags: vegetables, fertilizer

[image]

I have some spoiled mayonnaise somewhat similar to in this picture. I was wondering whether it is possible to use it as an alternative for molasses in liquid fertilizer fermentation.

Comment: Just bury the spoiled mayo somewhere non-critical, at least 6" deep but not a lot deeper. As Stephie says, it's not helping the things you want to help in your fertilizer, but it will break down eventually and that deep it should not attract anything to dig it up, while still being in a relatively bio-active zone.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn’t recommend that.

Molasses is - simplified - liquid sugar with minerals, so a carbohydrate. It feeds a certain range of bacteria that need sugars. We know similar mechanisms from sourdough, yogurt and wine making, where carbohydrates are fermented.

Mayonnaise is mostly fat and a bit of protein. So it will also feed microorganisms (as evidenced by the spoilage), but those are not the same that you want to feed with the molasses.

And for your fertilizer, it means the mayonnaise will not help your fermentation process and possibly hinder it by giving unwanted microorganisms a boost.